# How do I convert an AbstractAuthListener from symfony 2.5 to symfony 2.6 when getToken and setToken signature have changed

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

Symfony 2.6 deprecated security.context and split it into token_storage and authorization_checker services.

The provided examples in the upgrade docs do fine explaining how to upgrade controllers that use the security.context service, but say little about what to do in the Authentication system itself.

Specifically, prior to 2.6 security.context service had a getToken and setToken function who had a single optional argument of token.  The new token_storage service has getToken and setToken functions, but they require a tokenid and a token.  The cannonical example documentation for doing custom authentication (see the [2.7 Custom Authentication Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)) still shows passing just a token to setToken, although it is updated to show using the token_storage service.

Has anyone who has upgrade from <=2.5 to >=2.6 successfully implemented custom authentication and if so can you tell where/how I should obtain the necessary tokenId for passing to the setToken and getToken methods?

Example code from pre-2.6 inside of AbstractAuthListener->handle function:

```
        $previousToken = $this->securityContext->getToken();
        $authToken = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);
        $this->securityContext->setToken($authToken);
        ...// various other code
        catch(\Exception $ex){$this->securityContext->setToken() //clearing security context due to exception during authentication.
```

post 2.6 getToken shows a required parameter of $tokenId and setToken requires both $tokenId and $token

Comment: As far as I can see [it's still optional](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.html) ? The example in your link shows it's used in exactly the same way as pre-2.6?

Comment: Yeah that's what the example shows.  The example doesn't actually work anymore. It IS required and the example/docs are wrong.

Comment: [The corresponding file](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.php) still (even in 3.4) has setToken take an optional argument and getToken take no argument at all.

Comment: PS: I updated from 2.3 to 2.7 without changing anything in my authentication listener. I still call `getToken` without any argument and it's working fine (using a custom SSL certificate field for email authentication)

Comment: To quote the [UPGRADE-2.6](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.6.md) document: *This change is 100% Backwards Compatible as the SecurityContext delegates the methods.*